# Maximum Likelihood of P(x<a) = a and P(x<a) = a^2 number generators given a sample

Tags: probability, statistics, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

The question asked: *There are two number generators. Given a sample, which of these generators is it from?*

*1) generates a random number uniformly between 0 and 1 with* $P(x<a) = a$

*2) generates a random number uniformly between 0 and 1 with* $P(x<a) = a^2$

*The samples are {0.1,0.2,0.3} (belongs to G1) and {0.9,0.8,0.7} (belongs to G2)*

My question is:

**1) If it is a uniform distribution between 0 and 1 how can it have** $F_x = a \ $

**2) Assuming they meant** $0<x<1 \ and \ f_x=a \ $ **for G1 and** $0<x<1 \ and \ f_x=a^2 \ $ **for G2; do I have to use the likelihood estimator and if so how?**

I tried finding the PDF of G1 by differentiating "a" but I get 0 and I dont know what that means. Im still learning so I'm not sure if I'm making mistakes or if the question is sketchy.

Comment: There is a typo. A uniform number in $[0,1]$ such that $P(x<a)=a$ is ok, but of course it can't be $P(x<a)=a^2$: this one is not uniform. You seem to be missing the point: the CDF of the first is $F(a)=a$. $a$ is not a constant.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. So having "a" as the variant, how can I solve the question to find which is the most likely generator?

Comment: You could compare the likelihood of the sample with each distribution. After all, that's the title of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first generator samples randomly from $\mathsf{Unif}(0,1) \equiv \mathsf{Beta}(1,1),$ which has *density* function $f_1(x) = 1,$ for $0 \le x \le 1.$

The second generator samples randomly from $\mathsf{Beta}(2,1),$ which has *density* function $f_2(x) = 2x,$ for $0 \le x \le 1.$ [Perhaps see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) on beta distributions.]

The likelihood function of a sample given a distribution is the product of the density evaluated at each sample value. For the first generator, the likelihood function is $L_1(\mathbf{x_1}) = L_1(\mathbf{x_2}) = 1$ for both samples.

For the second generator, you should get
$L_2(\mathbf{x_1}) = 0.048$ for the first sample
and $L_2(\mathbf{x_2}) = 4.032.$

Computations in R, but easy to do by hand: [In R, `dbeta` is a beta density function; the 2nd and 3rd parameters of this R function are the shape parameters of the particular beta distribution.]

```
x1 = c(.1,.2,.3);  x2 = (.9,.8,.7)
prod(dbeta(x1,2,1))
[1] 0.048
prod(dbeta(x2,2,1))
[1] 4.032
```

With that information you should be able to use the likelihood functions to say which sample comes from which distribution.

*Intuitive approach:* Here are the density functions for the two distributions:

[image]

It makes sense that the sample with more relatively large
observations should have come from the second generator.